# Ubuntu doesn't recognize thunderbolt port on my Mac Mini

Tags: mac, external-monitor, thunderbolt

I have a working install disk which works perfectly fine on my MacBook, but when I boot to it on my Mac Mini and select 'Install Ubuntu' the monitor goes to sleep, and the computer stays on.  The only way I figured out that it is still running is the fact that I heard one of the Ubuntu noises.  The monitor is plugged in via thunderbolt and uses the Apple brand thunderbolt to VGA.  I've done some looking around but found nothing.  I don't have any way to test whether HDMI works.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a 2011 Mac Mini with that very same adaptor you speak of.  This adaptor exhibited this problem on bootup every time.  Switching to HDMI solved the problem, but you can also try these:

1. Unplug and replug the adaptor *after* bootup.
2. Purchase a different brand/model adaptor, especially if the one you have is old/cheapo (note: this isn't as likely to work).

Comment: "uses the Apple brand thunderbolt to VGA" -- so that second one won't help.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried doing it after boot up, but I'll try again. I've been planning to get an hdmi one anyway, so I'll do that.